# $V{REPORT_COUNT} not counting logically

Tags: count, jasper-reports

I'm using the `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` function in *iReport* to generate row numbers per `ID`, but when an `ID` has more than one `Value` it is using the rows to add to the row count giving the current output below.

**Current Output**

```
Row Number  ID  Value
1           23  A
2           65  N
3           89  P
4           34  B
                Q
                A
7           77  B
```

I want the output to be like the below with each row number only incriminating by `ID`

**$V{REPORT_COUNT} Settings**

Print Repeated Values is TRUE

Evaluation Time is NOW

**Desired Output**

```
Row Number  ID  Value
1           23  A
2           65  N
3           89  P
4           34  B
                Q
                A
5           77  B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldnt use $V{REPORT_COUNT} as it counts the number of rows in the report and the value cannot be manipulated as this is an inbuilt variable But a workaround was that create Report Group Based on ID  and create a variable that just counts ID , set Increment Type to Group --> (ID) and Reset Type is set to Report. This will count the unique ID's

I then moved Rownumber, ID and Value in the Group Header and put Value in the detail band though the value text field in the detail band will have the Print When Expression: $V{ID_Count} != 1 (This will remove the repetition)